# Wordpress - Doubts about plugins able to store data

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a system in which the user can register data and it must be stored somewhere, so that other users will be able to view it if they desire to do so.

This data must have a numeric value, in which the user would be able to register and save as much data as he desires.

I am thinking in using a Wordpress` plugin to create such kind of control.

However I would need reliable plugins, because I cannot lose the data that I will be storing.

Does anyone know any plugins that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: i think you are looking for something like https://toolset.com/  (my favorite) or https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/  (i dont know it, but i think it has a free version)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at them.